# Laravel 4.2 oneToMany relationship issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Despite having implemented many L4 relationships and them working most of the time. I am struggling and for some reason cannot see where I have gone wrong. It is almost certainly something obvious.

The relationship is that A task has one topic, topics have many tasks.

Task Model

```
class Task extends Eloquent {


    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(

    );

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Resource');
    }


    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Topic', 'topic_id');
    }

    }
```

Topic Model

```
class Topic extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();


    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }

}
```

Task Controller

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $task = $this->task->where('number', $id);

        return View::make('tasks.show', compact('task'));
    }
```

when I dd ($task) the relations array is empty.

> object(Task)#688 (21) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL
>   ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=>
>   int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
>   ["attributes":protected]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9"
>   ["number"]=> string(1) "6" ["topic"]=> string(1) "2" ["topic_old"]=>
>   string(10) "War Effort" ["task"]=> string(28) "You want us to collect
>   Moss?" ["objective"]=> string(36) "Collecting Information including
>   Q&A" ["method"]=> string(29) "Supported historical research"
>   ["context"]=> string(0) "" ["level"]=> string(0) "" ["created_at"]=>
>   string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19)
>   "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } ["original":protected]=> array(11) { ["id"]=>
>   string(1) "9" ["number"]=> string(1) "6" ["topic"]=> string(1) "2"
>   ["topic_old"]=> string(10) "War Effort" ["task"]=> string(28) "You
>   want us to collect Moss?" ["objective"]=> string(36) "Collecting
>   Information including Q&A" ["method"]=> string(29) "Supported
>   historical research" ["context"]=> string(0) "" ["level"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=>
>   string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0)
>   { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true)
>   ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) }

Comment: DB tasks table has `topic_id `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the relationship that you declare in the model before. In this case I will use `Eager Loading`, `with()` function.

```
$tasks = $this->task->where('number', $id)->with('topic');
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

> I would like to change the variable to `$tasks` because using
>   `where()`, you will get instant of
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` (many results)

And you can check the result by.

```
dd($tasks->get());
```